# Sort the array in a specific order in jQuery

Tags: javascript

```
var i="q=brand:GOOD_EARTH,LIPTON:blend:Black,Herbal:varieties:Tea&layoutStatus=grid&show=Page&sort=popular-all";
var x=0;
var s=[], arr=[];
var temp={};
var myarray=["blend", "varieties", "brand"];

s=i.split('q=')[1].split('&')[0].split(':');

console.log(s);

for(x=0;x<s.length;x=x+2){ 
temp[s[x]] = s[x+1];
arr[x]= s[x];
}
console.log(temp);
```

// sample value

```
 temp = {
    blend:"Black,Herbal"
    brand:"GOOD_EARTH,LIPTON"
    varieties:"Tea" }


 s= [0:"brand"
1:"GOOD_EARTH,LIPTON"
2:"blend"
3:"Black,Herbal"
4:"varieties"
5:"Tea"]

arr=[
0:"brand"
2:"blend"
4:"varieties" ]
```

Above are sample values for s and temp. I need to sort "arr" in the specified "myarray" order. How can I do this can anyone please help. Thank you all in advance.

Comment: It's at this point where we used to ask what the original poster had tried…

Comment: You cannot sort an object. If you need order, you need an array.

Comment: sorry I can't get you. can you tell in brief

Comment: @Mahi Explaining you in an answer with solution. Please wait.

Comment: Ok i stored the keys in a specific array.   for(x=0;x<s.length;x=x+2){ 
arr[x]= s[x]; } . how can I do the sort using "myarray"

Comment: @Mahi Nopes. It's not possible. Felix is right. This is confusing.

Answer (score -1):

You need to use the [`.sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) by giving some following values:

```
blend:      1
varieties:  2
brand:      3
```

The `sort` callback function takes up two arguments. Current and next. You need to replace the value with current and next. But with your current example, it is not possible. Or may be I am unclear of what I am expecting to achieve.

I am not answering this as an answer. So, feel free to modify, comment, meh.

Comment: Now i stored the values in arr `for(x=0;x<s.length;x=x+2){ arr[x]= s[x]; }`how can i sort this using myarray values . sample `arr=[
0:"brand"
2:"blend"
4:"varieties" ]`

Comment: @Mahi What you have given is not an array boss.

Comment: Please could you tell me how to sort a array in a specific mentioned order.

Comment: @Mahi **That's not an array!**

Comment: Ya .can please give me an example to sort an array

Comment: Check the [`.sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)'s manual. It has some examples, that you can use.

Comment: sort() sort the values in asc order right, but I need to sort the array in the specific format

Comment: @Mahi: Have a look at the documentation again. You can provide provide a callback to `.sort` to determine the order.